# Do not understand error message about NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: ios, exception, crash

My application is going to crash for a reason I don't know.
I am getting an error like this:

> " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   viewController."

Comment: Sorry to be completely discouraging, but, it's not "going to crash". It has *already crashed*.

Comment: One would think that `NSUnknownKeyException` is pretty clear? Your application is trying to set a value for an unknown key... Without seeing the code I doubt anybody will tell you more than that.

Comment: One thing to check is that you have no warnings in your nibs in interface builder.

Comment: Post the copy of raised exception.

Comment: check for spelling mistake in classname when you are redirecting your viewcontroller to another view.

Answer (score 1):

This erro mainly appears when the connections of the XIB's `file's owner` are broken. You check this in the connections tab of the `file's owner`. There will be little exclamation mark at the right.